# Erro ao executar delete no banco Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Estou com um problema no meu projeto `Android`. Quando executo um `delete` no banco `sqlite`, obtenho como retorno a seguinte mensagem de log:

```
W/FileUtils: Failed to chmod(/storage/sdcard/Cardapio Digital/Database/dbcardapio.sqlite): 
android.system.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

public class PedidosDao {

```
Context context;
variaveis v;
SQLiteDatabase db;


public PedidosDao(Context context, variaveis v) {
    this.v = v;
    this.context = context;
}

public void deletaItem(int codigo){
    db = context.openOrCreateDatabase(v.getPathBanco(),Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE,null);

    try{

        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM PEDIDOS WHERE ID = "+codigo+" ");

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o código que está a usar.

Answer (score 4):

Acho que o código esta errado. vc ta colocando aspas duplas encima de aspas duplas sem a aspas simples(digamos que ele precisa entender que é uma string)....... 
Tente da seguinte maneira:

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM PEDIDOS WHERE ID = '"+codigo+"';");
```

ou então:

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM PEDIDOS WHERE ID = "+codigo);
```

Editando:
A descrição do erro parece indicar que falta alguma permissão. Tente colocar essa linhas no seu manifest.xml:

```
"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Comment: Não vejo o porque de dar erro... Na verdade eu criava meus "DELETES" dessa maneira que descrevi. Hoje já não uso mais assim, faço o DELETE de uma maneira diferente, segue uma url que explica melhor isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510219/deleting-row-in-sqlite-in-android

Comment: o erro parece ser referente a permissões, mo meu manifest esta tudo ok, tem as permissoes, eu consigo gravar registros e ler os registros, quando vou deletar me mostra o log : W/FileUtils: Failed to chmod(/storage/sdcard/Cardapio Digital/Database/dbcardapio.sqlite): 
android.system.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Comment: @AndreGuedes acho que o problema esta na forma em como você está tentando deletar os dados do banco, acredito que não seja a forma recomendada. Se quiser eu posto uma resposta com a forma recomendada pela documentação, mas você terá que mudar boa parte de como você estava fazendo as coisas até agora.